# check multiple textarea containing same value javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a form that's created in a loop via php

it's something like this

```
<textarea name="iflair_qpress_que_st[]" style="width:355px;height:100px">Qsort Mid Point 4</textarea>
```

and user can add multiple textarea.

and im trying to validate the textareas which have **same value**.

Comment: That's nice. Did you have a question?

Comment: Do you want to validate on server or client side? Code example would be helpful.

Comment: I'm inferring he wants to check in Javascript based on the title, but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Given a lack of specifics, the easiest way in JavaScript to test if two textareas are equal would be

```
if (document.getElementById('textArea1').value == document.getElementById('textArea2').value) {
   // equal values, do something.
}
```

Maybe, you're unsure how many text areas you have?  jQuery will help you get all the textareas,
and from there you could do something like the below code:

```
var allTAs = $('textarea');
var iTAValue;

for (var i = 0, il = allTAs.length - 1; i < il; i++) {
    iTAValue = allTAs[i].value;
    for (var j = i + 1, jl = allTAs.length; j < jl; j++) {
         if (iTAValue == allTAs[j].value) {
             // equal values, do something.
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not exactly sure how you want to check the values. But here is a code sample i created that might help:

```
var ele = $("textarea");

$(ele).each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Hello"){
        // Do your validation for "Hello" here.
        $(this).css('background-color','blue');
    }
    else if($(this).val() == "Test"){
        // Do your validation for "Test" here.
        $(this).css('background-color','green');
    }
});
```

So for each textarea element you can check if the value is equal to what you need to check against then do your validation within that if.

I have posted a link to an example that I have created here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Boldonglen/6HeXV/)